# Struggling with Picking & Cropping an Image

Tags: android, image, crop

I'm trying to let the user:

1. Click on an ImageView
2. Pick an Image
3. Crop the Image
4. Finally display the cropped Image in the ImageView

So far it kinda works, but I've got a few issues:

- After choosing the Image, the User gets asked AGAIN which program he wants to use for cropping. I don't want that
- The cropping intent displays the area-to-crop as a circle. I'd rather have a square!

Thanks for any help guys, here's the complete class:

```
public class settings extends Activity {
ImageView masterUserImg;
private static int LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS = 1;
final int PIC_CROP = 1;
```

@Override

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);

    masterUserImg=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.masterUserImage);


    masterUserImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Create the Intent for Image Gallery.
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            // Start new activity with the LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS to handle back the results when image is picked from the Image Gallery.
            startActivityForResult(i, LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS);

        }

    });

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Uri pickedImage = null;

    // 1) PICK IMAGE
    if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        pickedImage = data.getData();
    }

    // 2) CROP IMAGE
    performCrop(pickedImage);

    // 3) LOAD IMAGE
    if (requestCode == PIC_CROP) {
        if (data != null) {
            // get the returned data
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            // get the cropped bitmap
            Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");

            masterUserImg.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap);
        }
    }
}

private void performCrop(Uri picUri) {
    try {

        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        // indicate image type and Uri
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        // set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        // indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        // indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 128);
        // retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // display an error message
        String errorMessage = "Crop failed";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this [Cropper Library](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper) . It will fulfill your requirement.

It supports features which you needed .

Answer (score 0):

For not prompt activity for cropping, you can try query activities for `CROP` intent and use one of them. For querying activities available for certain intent, please consult the [document](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20int)).

For the circle shape of crop area, it's the implementation of the activity which is handling the crop intent, there's no way to change that if you don't known how to configure it with correct extras parameters.

But as @CommonsWare said, there's no `com.android.camera.action.CROP` intent, there will be phones have no activity to handle that.

So you should use a crop library to handle that, like [android-crop](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop).
Finally, for your requirement, you can try [droid-image-picker](http://github.com/egistli/droid-image-picker) which let you select image from gallery and camera, and also integrate android crop for the cropping part.

Disclosure: I'm the developer of droid image picker